# running first custom method in cordova

Tags: javascript, cordova

I am new in Cordova. I have a fresh installed project. I did not change anything and the app is running now on our Android device.

I added following lines before `</body>` and after linking script files to `index.html` but it not working.

1. Where is the issue?
2. Where is the best place for adding own methods?

   ```
   <script type="text/javascript">
       document.onload = function(){
           alert("hi!");
       }
   </script>
   ```

Answer (score 1):

You first need to make sure that the file you're editing is located inside the `/www` folder in the root of your project folder.

Yes, you can add your scripts inside the `index.html`. If you have your files inside the `/www` folder like I mentioned, then you'll have to run `cordova prepare` in the terminal every time you add/edit any file inside that folder. This gets all files inside www and copies them to their respective platforms, in this case, it will be copied to the Android platform.

Then, build the project for Android again like normal.

Comment: thanks. I entered cordova prepare command and says android studio project detected. we run the app in real device using cordova run android and app be run. but still alert not working.

Comment: Try `cordova build`. I usually just open Android Studio and build it that way.